# Get values from javascript slider

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use a Bootstrap price range slider in by shop, but I don't really know how to get the value into PHP. I have this code in my bootstrap-slider.js file:

```html
$(function() {

  $("#pricelimit")
  .slider({})
  .on('slide', function() {
    $('#output').html(this.value);
  }).trigger('slide');

});
```

And then I have this code in my html file:

```html
<script>
  var slidervalue = ......
</script>

<?php
  $slidervalue="<script>document.writeln(slidervalue);</script>";
?>
```

What do I have to put after 'var slidervalue' to get the value from the slider?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  var slidervalue = $('#output').val();
</script>
```

That should work, I assume that value is stored in id output, right ? If that is not working - can you please provide your html and js in codepen, jsbin ?

Comment: It now says 'undefined'. I have put your code in my test.php file and I have this in my bootstrap-slider.js file.

$(function() {

  $("#pricelimit")
  .slider({})
  .on('slide', function() {
    $('#output').html(this.value);
  }).trigger('slide');

});

I use <?php echo "<script>document.writeln(slidervalue);</script>"; ?> to echo the value. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get a variable from client at server side,
you have to transmit it to server, by GET or POST.

a example for POST:

### in js (use jquery):

```
$.post('test.php',{var1:123},function(){console.log('post ok!')});
```

will post the var1 to server

### in test.php:

```
$_POST['var1']
```

will get the var1 posted by client.